# grammatical flaw in message when an edit is queued for review

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I edited a question for the first time, so my edit was queued for review.

The message I received was:

```
Thanks for your edit!
This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.
```

I think it should read:

This edit **will** only be visible to you **once** it is peer reviewed.

Comment: What's grammatically wrong on it?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the message that I can see.

Comment: to clarify, "peer reviewed" means reviewed by someone with edit privledges.

Comment: Sigh. I was obviously caffeine-deficient when I wrote this.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a flaw. The last fragment means "until someone with enough reputation review and approve it".

The fragment *can* be changed to "and it will be visible to others once your edit is reviewed" but personally can't see any reason to change it, the current grammar is just fine.